# labelFunction for JSON model object in AngularJS Directives

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am fairly new to Angular. I want to create a custom multi-select search box in Angular which I have done partially. Refer to this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/5YCCdDSnpHKRU51R9vCL?p=preview

In the above plunk, I see the multi-select working for names. How do I make the same widget generic? How do I provide the functionality that the user can choose which key:value pair to display in the multi-select.

For eg:

```
$scope.users = [
  {name: 'Dave', id: 24},
  {name: 'Tim', id: 22},
  {name: 'Laura', id: 20}
];
```

Currently names are being displayed. What if I want to display ids instead of names?

Can I create something like this:

```
<user-info-card users="users" label="id">
<user-info-card users="users" label="name">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new parameter in the scope of your directive

```
scope: {
    users: '=',
    label : '@'
  }
```

and use users[label] in your template

http://plnkr.co/edit/O5NeMRjpSGEISWbmiY9e?p=preview

Comment: Thank you! You are awesome!